# Force my app to use the VPN configuration,when making a connection via AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am working on an enterprise app which is distributed via AirWatch and the configuration profile is setup on a per app basis which allows VPN connectivity.

The issue is that when my app tries to send a HTTP Request to a machine in the VPN, I get a Host Not Found error which means that my app is not utilizing the VPN at all.

How can I force my app to use the VPN configuration sent by AirWatch when making a connection via AFNetworking?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure the use of per-app VPN in the assignment tab.

Go to the app detail tab, choose "assign" and edit the current assignment.
Make sure the **App tunneling** is enabled and choose the **Per-App VPN Profile** that the app should use.

Every VPN profile needs to use an external app to connect. Usually it's the **Airwatch Tunnel app**, make sure it's correctly configured